# Как извлечь правильные значения из jquery ui slider? Весь код внутри

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Собственно извлечь у меня получилось, но вот извлекаются неправильно, при движении ползунка извлекается значение на 1 меньше.

пробовал использовать разные события, но мне нужно именно событие slide, то есть чтобы значение извлекалось при движении ползунка.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#topslider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 24,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
      b = $("#bottomslider").slider('value');
      summ = a * b;
     // console.log(summ);
      $('.a').val(a);
      $('.b').val(b);
      $('.summ').val(summ);
    }
  });
  $("#bottomslider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
      b = $("#bottomslider").slider('value');
      summ = a * b;
      //console.log(summ);
      $('.a').val(a);
      $('.b').val(b);
      $('.summ').val(summ);
    }
  });
  a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
  b = $("#bottomslider").slider('value');
  summ = a * b;
 // console.log(summ);
  $('.a').val(a);
  $('.b').val(b);
  $('.summ').val(summ);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <label>Сколько часов в день Вы готовы работать?</label>
    <div id="topslider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <label>Сколько дней Вы готовы работать?</label>
    <div id="bottomslider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label>Ваш доход составит</label>
    <div class="content-wt">
      <div class="content-yell"></div>
    </div>
    a<input class="a" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'><br/> б
    <input class="b" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'><br/> сумма
    <input class="summ" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'>
    <label>руб./месяц*</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо того чтобы брать необновленное значение из DOM, нужно взять его из контекста:

```
  $("#bottomslider").slider({
  ...
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
      b = ui.value
```

т.е. `ui.value` вместо `$(...).slider('value');`

**Рабочий код:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#topslider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 24,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      a = ui.value;
      b = $("#bottomslider").slider('value');
      summ = a * b;
     // console.log(summ);
      $('.a').val(a);
      $('.b').val(b);
      $('.summ').val(summ);
    }
  });
  $("#bottomslider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
      b = ui.value;
      summ = a * b;
      //console.log(summ);
      $('.a').val(a);
      $('.b').val(b);
      $('.summ').val(summ);
    }
  });
  a = $("#topslider").slider('value');
  b = $("#bottomslider").slider('value');
  summ = a * b;
 // console.log(summ);
  $('.a').val(a);
  $('.b').val(b);
  $('.summ').val(summ);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/scripts/jquery.ui.slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://auto.v056.ru/sites/all/libraries/calc/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <label>Сколько часов в день Вы готовы работать?</label>
    <div id="topslider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <label>Сколько дней Вы готовы работать?</label>
    <div id="bottomslider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label>Ваш доход составит</label>
    <div class="content-wt">
      <div class="content-yell"></div>
    </div>
    a<input class="a" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'><br/> б
    <input class="b" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'><br/> сумма
    <input class="summ" type='text' value='0' readonly='readonly'>
    <label>руб./месяц*</label>
  </div>
</div>
```